# Scanner и мой пример

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите целое число");
        int a = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);

        System.out.println("Введите строку");
        String b = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(b);

        System.out.println("Введите дробное число");
        double c = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

После `System.out.println("Введите целое число");`, я ввожу целое число и оно мне показывает в консоли `System.out.println(a);` . Потом сразу идет  `System.out.println("Введите строку");` , но я не могу ввести строку так как  меня перенаправляет сразу к введите дробное число, где я ввожу 25,5 к примеру и вижу потом в консоли `25.5` благодаря `System.out.println(c);`.
А что со строкой?

Comment: Рекомендую пройтись дебагером и посмотреть что происходит. Будет хорошее понимание процесса отладки. Проблема сама по себе не очень сложная, легко поймёте

Comment: @maklas запускал дебаг, а он останавливается где нужно ввести в консоль данные, а я не могу найти это место куда вводить

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавьте после `scan.nextInt();` также `scan.nextLine();`.

Дело в том, что [nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) считывает символы до получения числа, а остальные символы, включая символ перевода строки останутся и при вызове [nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) будет дочитывание их начиная с ранее считанного числа и до конца строки.

Работающий пример:

```
    System.out.println("Введите целое число");
    int a = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(a);

    System.out.println("Введите строку");
    String b = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(b);

    System.out.println("Введите дробное число");
    double c = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(c);
```